# make nested set interval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, intervals

I have a function call from set interval function and is to be carried out in each 1 mt. But now its working depends on the parent iteration 0.5 mt.

```
 let intervalA;
let intervalB;
var timeInMinuts;
const a = () =>
  // Assign the interval to global variable
  timeInMinuts = 60000;
  intervalA = window.setInterval(function() {
  const today = new Date();
  const time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();

  console.log('A: ' + time);
  // Check if event is assigned and then instantiate the intevalB
  if (!intervalB) b();
   } , 30000);

const b = () => {

  // Assign the interval to global variable
  intervalB =  setInterval(function() {
  const today = new Date();
  let time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  console.log('B: ' + time);
  }, timeInMinuts);  
}
```

// Create first interval
a();
note : need code as like this like calling a set interval function from another.
I need o/p as
A: 10:32:34 
B: 10:33:4 
A: 10:33:4 
A: 10:33:34

Comment: Why's the top timeout 30,000 and not 60,000 as well?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? It's hard to understand. Right now you're creating new intervals every 30 seconds, those intervals themselves will execute in 60 seconds, but they are created 30 seconds apart.

Comment: `expected as ...` what happenned to the `setInterval(..., 30000)`? You don't have any 30 second gaps in yout expected output. Where are they?

Comment: i have modified my question slightly . Could you please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should separate each interval and assign them to a global variable in order to clear them if needed.

**Note:** `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` are not [reliable for exact timing operation](https://medium.com/@abhi9bakshi/why-javascript-timer-is-unreliable-and-how-can-you-fix-it-9ff5e6d34ee0), for that type of task you should refer to the clock time each time through `Date()`, maybe with smaller interval checks. Alternatives are `requestAnimationFrame()` and *web workers*.

```js
// Store the interval in global variables so them are reachable to be cleared from any function
let intervalA;
let intervalB;

const a = () =>
  // Assign the interval to global variable
  intervalA = window.setInterval(function() {
  const today = new Date();
  const time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  
  console.log('A: ' + time);
  // Check if event is assigned and then instantiate the intevalB
  if (!intervalB) b();
   } , 30000);

const b = () => {
  const timeInMinuts = 60000;
  // Assign the interval to global variable
  intervalB =  setInterval(function() {
  const today = new Date();
  let time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  console.log('B: ' + time);
  }, 60000);  
}

// Create first interval
a();
```

- After 30s callback A is called (global time 30s) and B is istantiated with 60s delay
- After 30s callback A is caled (golbal time 60s) and B has 30s before start
- After 30s A is called and B is called (global time 90s)

Now on, every 30s:

- A
- AB
- A
- AB
- ...etc

Comment: i want to call intervalB from A. because i will get the timeInMinuts as a database value from A. So i need to run the intervalB in that selected value from A

Comment: Modified the example to fit your request.

Comment: i have modified my question slightly as per your code. Could you please check it.